I can't use drag and drop Windows to Ubuntu in VMware
I can't use drag and drop as well as copy/paste in Windows to Ubuntu (VMware Workstation). I turned on drag and drop as well as copy/paste.
Recently I had a shared folder problem, that is not showing even though I added it. Then I run sudo vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs just mount the file and then it works.
Version details:

VMware Workstation 17 pro - 17.6.2
Ubuntu - 24.04.1 LTS
kernel - 6.8.0-51-generic

I tried:

Changed  .vmx "isolation.tools.copy.disable = FALSE"
"isolation.tools.paste.disable = FALSE"
Reinstalled VMware tools (it works for a while then back to 1)
Turned off Wayland, but it is still not working.
VMware updated.

Note:
drag and drop as well as copy/paste works well in other guest OSs such as Windows and Kali Linux, but not in Ubuntu.

Its a Ubuntu Desktop Latest version and VMware Workstation Pro 17.6.2. i am using gnome.

Well I changed few things in it and set-up an dev environment so i don't wanna move to 24.10 to do all the setup from scratch again
